# How to sum 90+ Arrays with using function?

Tags: php

I would like to sum up several arrays. I have a script that dynamically creates arrays without name. Below is an example. In my script i have a 90+ arrays. I want to sum up all it. All keys in that arrays be user id, so i only want sum values of keys. How to do it? Regards

```
Array 
( 
[1] => 1 
[2] => 1 
[3] => 1 
) 
Array 
( 
[1] => 1 
[2] => 1 
) 
Array 
( 
[1] => 1 
)
```

I want to get only one array result like:

```
Array 
( 
[1] => 3 
[2] => 2
[3] => 1
)
```

Comment: `I have a script that dynamically creates arrays without name.` and how are these arrays stored? Maybe you should tell us what exactly your goal is

Comment: @kuh-chan Main post edited.

Comment: Again, what does this even mean _arrays without name_ ???

Comment: @AbraCadaver That means i have only that 90+ arrays without any sum system.

Comment: Again: how are they stored? Do you write the arrays dynamically in a file? If so - how?

Comment: @kuh-chan No, it be stored in a that php file. So every loop that function create array with data.

Comment: Should probably show the loop so that you can add each array into another main array, or maybe sum in the loop that creates the arrays.

Comment: FYI: array keys begin with `[0]`, not `[1]`. (that could save hours of error hunting)

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

Add all your arrays into one array.

```
$all_arrays[] =Array 
( 
[1] => 1 ,
[2] => 1, 
[3] => 1 
); 

$all_arrays[] = Array 
( 
[1] => 1, 
[2] => 1 
) ;

$all_arrays[] = Array 
( 
[1] => 1 
);

 $results = [];
foreach($all_arrays as $arr){
   foreach($arr as $user_id=>$value){
       if(in_array($user_id,$results)){
           $results[$user_id] = $results[$user_id] + $value;
       }else{
            $results[$user_id] = $value;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify all arrays in the `array_merge`:

```
$result = array_count_values(array_keys(array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3)));
```

If you can get the arrays dynamically added to another `$main_array` like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

Then it would be much easier:

```
$result = array_count_values(array_keys(array_merge(...$main_array)));
```